# LinearGradient visible color divisions

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The `LinearGradient` feature for me is showing visible lines or divisions between each shade of color like in this image here for both my physical OLED phone and my PC monitor:

[image]

How do I fix this? I have tried `Paint.enableDithering = true;` before and after `runApp` but it doesn't do anything.